# Row Flatener not properly handling NULL values

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

(1) Rows contain individual data attributes for a record
(2) Properly assign all target fields to match the desired record
(3) When a NULL value the flattenerskips the element rather then setting to empty field
(4) Order of attributes is askew from that point on

No solution yet

When a target field is missing the row flattener should supply a NULL or empty data attribute and maintain the "record" layout versus skipping to the next record

Comment: Can you please supply the Pentaho version number? Can you please show what your input data is and what your expect your output data to be? Perhaps also supply us with the settings in the steps you're using.

Comment: Version 8.3   I am limited here because of space. There us REST Call that returns results. JSON INPUT is then used to get body fields. Filter Rows is used to exclude rows with length greater than 200 ( a kludge because of unusual structure of JSON response data structure. A record  has twelve data elements spread out in 12 columns that need to be flattened into one row. The REST result in POSTMAN has NULL values for some of the data attributes. In row flattener these NULL attributes are skipped when NULL.